# Body SMS Twilio in app iOS

Tags: ios, twilio

I'm making an app for iphone and sending SMS using Twilio for automatic form to send a message when an event determined by the user. I have everything ready but when sending the message only sends the last variable declared, when you have to send the whole body with the three variables. Why can this happen?

```
NSString *kMessage = (@"%@ %@ %@ %@.", tunombre, _addressOutlet.text, _cityOutlet.text, coordinateLabel.text);
```

Only send the last variable coordinateLabel.text. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not properly concatenating the strings.

Try:

```
NSString *kMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@",tunombre, _addressOutlet.text, _cityOutlet.text, coordinateLabel.text];
```